# Django Apache and Virtualenv ImportError: No module named site

Tags: django, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, centos6

The error from apache after a 504 page

```
[info] mod_wsgi (pid=): Python home /var/venv/mybox.
[info] mod_wsgi (pid=): Initializing Python.
ImportError: No module named site
```

This is with a barely configured app.

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi.c>
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/var/venv/mybox
WSGIProcessGroup myapp
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/web/myapp/wsgi.py
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<Directory /var/www/html/web>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Followed every post and tutorial I can. I am on CENTOS6 . using virutal env python 2.7 the default system env is 2.6

```
$ ldd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc06174000)
```

mywsgi.py

```
 import os,sys     
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application     
 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
 sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/html/web')
 activate_this = '/var/venv/mybox/bin/activate_this.py'
 execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

PYHTONHOME is not set

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for using virtual environments with mod_wsgi can be found at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Most important in your case is the section:

- [Virtual Environment and Python Version](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#virtual-environment-and-python-version)

In that section it states:

> When using a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi, it is very important that it has been created using the same Python installation that mod_wsgi was originally compiled for. It is not possible to use a Python virtual environment to force mod_wsgi to use a different Python version, or even a different Python installation.
>
> You cannot for example force mod_wsgi to use a Python virtual environment created using Python 3.5 when mod_wsgi was originally compiled for Python 2.7. This is because the Python library for the Python installation it was originally compiled against is linked directly into the mod_wsgi module.

So most likely what is happening is that mod_wsgi is compiled for Python 2.6. You cannot in this case force it to use a Python virtual environment created from Python 2.7. When you do this, you will get the error you see about `site` module being missing.

You will need to uninstall that mod_wsgi from system packages and install mod_wsgi from source code, compiling it against Python 2.7. The easiest way to do this might be to use the `pip install` method as described in:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Run `pip install` to install it in your virtual environment and then follow instructions in section 'Connecting into Apache installation' about configuring Apache to use it.

Comment: Cannot load /var/venv/mybox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so into server:  cannot open shared object file: Permission denied. I tried changing permission

Comment: Your SELinux profile is most likely not allowing Apache to use stuff in that location. Try having virtual environment under ``/var/www``.

Comment: Installing mod_wsgi using pip and moving the virtualenv to /var/www worked. This is an internal site so we can make that compromise

Answer (score 8):

### Solved in CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4.6

My whole server uses Python 2.7, but I've already installed Python 3.6 and my virtualenv is using Python 3.6.

After configured djang.conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf) with this code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIDaemonProcess myProj python-home=/home/user/django-site/env python-path=/home/user/django-site
WSGIProcessGroup myProj
WSGIScriptAlias /myProj /home/user/django-site/my-project/wsgi.py


Alias /static /home/user/django-site/static
<Directory /home/user/django-site/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/django-site/my-project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And restarted my apache

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

I got this error a thousand lines (/var/log/httpd/error_log)

```
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
ImportError: No module named site
```

### The solution

First:

```
sudo grep wsgi /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

I got this:

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 62324] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.33 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Note the Python version (2.7.5). What I did to get mod_wsgi according to my Python 3.6 is using:

```
yum list *mod_wsgi*
Installed packages
mod_wsgi.x86_64                          3.4-18.el7                          @base
Disponible packages
python35u-mod_wsgi.x86_64                4.6.2-1.ius.centos7                 ius
python36u-mod_wsgi.x86_64                4.6.2-1.ius.centos7                 ius
```

and then I installed the package python36u-mod_wsgi.x86_64:

```
sudo yum install python36u-mod_wsgi.x86_64
```

Then I restarted Apache service:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

And got this new line from logs:

```
[Fri Mar 29 12:33:26.788716 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 76317] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.33 mod_wsgi/4.6.2 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

### And everything works! :-)

### Hope it helps you. C ya!

Comment: This worked for me on Centos 7 with a Python3.6 venv envirotnment.

Answer (score 1):

this is taken fron the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)
write this:
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
    WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

```
<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

and this is specifically for the virtual env, **you need to write the path to the site packeges of your python virtual env**:

```
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com:/path/to/your/venv/lib/python3.X/site-packages
```

the problem may also be in the -
[`PYTHONHOME`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME)

> Change the location of the standard Python libraries. By default, the
>   libraries are searched in prefix/lib/pythonversion and
>   exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion, where prefix and exec_prefix are
>   installation-dependent directories, both defaulting to /usr/local.
>
> When PYTHONHOME is set to a single directory, its value replaces both
>   prefix and exec_prefix. To specify different values for these, set
>   PYTHONHOME to prefix:exec_prefix.

Try to clean up your `PYTHONHOME`:

```
user$ export PYTHONHOME=
```

Comment: I initially followed that documentation to a T. Then I tried Graham Dumpleton blogs and tutorials. I always get the same error

Comment: try to change the pythonhome location

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, if you want to use python3, you will have to uninstall `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py` and install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` instead if you obtained your mod_wsgi from the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I was on centos6.X with python 2.7, reinstall of mod_wsgi has fixed the issue for me.

```
yum remove mod_wsgi.x86_64
yum install mod_wsgi.x86_64
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```